# Console not outputting information in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, console

I have a problem through pyautogui I need to know the position of my cursor but when I enter the code and press run in the console nothing happens
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi7rx.png)

I'm just starting to understand python

Answer (score 1):

You aren't running the file. Note how it says "Python Console" in the tab header. That indicates that no file is imported and run by default.

Right-click on the background of the editor, and press "Run file in Python console". You'll notice that it will open a new tab with a header of the file name, and your code will execute.

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but the question is how to make the code in the editor run in the console without copying it and pasting it into the console and using the button

Comment: @Сергей I don't understand what you mean. You don't need to copy and paste anything if the code is already in the editor.